# ChartJS stacked bar chart not displaying as stacked

Tags: php, chart.js, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to get a Bar chart to show as stacked but can't get it to work and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong...

I'm connected up to my Oracle table with the following results from my query...

```
Area | A  | B
Red  | 38 | 49
Blue | 31 | 38
```

My chart currently looks like this

[image]

And within my graph I've got the following...

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
  url: "getPiData.php",
  method: "POST",
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var CustomerModel = [];
    var DaysOut = [];
    for(var i in data) {
      DaysOut.push(data[i].A);
      DaysOut.push(data[i].B);
      CustomerModel.push("AREA");

    }
    $('#myChart3').remove();
    $('#barChartPi').append('<canvas id="myChart3"></canvas>');
    var chartdata = {
      labels: DaysOut,
      datasets : [
        {
          label:'Total Jobs' ,
          backgroundColor: "#22aa99",
          borderColor: "#22aa99",
          hoverBackgroundColor: "#22aa99",
          hoverBorderColor: "#22aa99",
          data: DaysOut
        },
      ]
    };
    var ctx = $("#myChart3");
    var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: chartdata,
      options: {
        legend: {
          display: false
       },
      scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            stacked: true,
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            stacked: true,
          }]
      },
    }
    });
  },
  //error: function(data) {
    //console.log(data);
  }
});
});
```

**EDIT:**

Made the following change to the graph...

```
    //console.log(data);
    var CustomerModel = [];
    var DaysOut_A = [];
    var DaysOut_B = [];
    for(var i in data) {
      // Set chart labels
      chartLabels = ['Week1', 'Week2','Week3','Week4', 'Week5']
      // Store data in separate array
      DaysOut_A.push(data[i].A);
      DaysOut_B.push(data[i].B);
    }
    $('#myChart1').remove();
    $('#piechartReason').append('<canvas id="myChart1"></canvas>');
    var chartdata = {
      labels: chartLabels,
      datasets : [
      {
        label:'Total Jobs A' ,   // Label for 1st Dataset
        backgroundColor: "#22aa99",
        borderColor: "#22aa99",
        hoverBackgroundColor: "#22aa99",
        hoverBorderColor: "#22aa99",
        data: DaysOut_A            // Data for 1st Dataset
      },{
        label:'Total Jobs B',      // Label for 2nd Dataset
        backgroundColor: "#aa2222",
        borderColor: "#aa2222",
        hoverBackgroundColor: "#aa2222",
        hoverBorderColor: "#aa2222",
        data: DaysOut_B           // Data for 2nd Dataset
      }
    ]
  };
```

**EDIT**

Adding array results from console

1. 0: {Area: "Red", A: "49", B: "49", …}
2. 1: { Area: "Blue ", A: "38", B: "35", …}

Comment: Stacked bar charts require multiple datasets, and you only have one.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is because you only have one dataset, and so chart.js displays everything along the x-axis. To create a stacked bar chart, you'll need to use multiple datasets. For this you'll have to store the data separately:

```
// Set chart labels
chartLabels = ['Red', 'Blue']
// Store data in separate array
DaysOut_A.push(data[i].A);
DaysOut_B.push(data[i].B);
```

And then create separate datasets for each:

```
var chartdata = {
  labels: chartLabels,         // Label for entire chart
  datasets : [
    {
      label:'Total Jobs A' ,   // Label for 1st Dataset
      backgroundColor: "#22aa99",
      borderColor: "#22aa99",
      hoverBackgroundColor: "#22aa99",
      hoverBorderColor: "#22aa99",
      data: DaysOut_A            // Data for 1st Dataset
    },{
      label:'Total Jobs B',      // Label for 2nd Dataset
      backgroundColor: "#aa2222",
      borderColor: "#aa2222",
      hoverBackgroundColor: "#aa2222",
      hoverBorderColor: "#aa2222",
      data: DaysOut_B           // Data for 2nd Dataset
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back, I made some changed (edited question above). The graph renders but it comes back empty. When I look at the array in the console all the values are there, but doesn't display any errors.

Comment: Can you share the resulting array once loaded to your page? If this is how your data looks then it works with the above example: 
{0 : {Area: 'Red', A: 38, B: 49},
1 : {Area: 'Blue', A: 31, B: 38}}

Comment: Yep, no problem. I've edited the question to include the array results.

Comment: A made a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hgbukz56/2/) that should help you see whats causing the issue in your version. Its possible that you havent included the right options to the chart or that the data is being read differently.